# Unwanted font Helvetica in PDF from Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

When I create a PDF from a Jasper Report, the resulting PDF declare to use "Helvetica" font, even if it doesn't contain text.
Unfortunately I cannot embed "Helvetica" font, because it is not among the Windows fonts.
Based on the PDF/A rules, I need to embed all the fonts in the PDF file.

How can I create  from Jasper  a PDF that doesn't declare to use Helvetica?

Thank you in advance.

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation by Teodor Danciu, the main architect of the JasperReports Library:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5368

Apparently, to avoid using Helvetica, you can create a default style that uses one of your fonts.

Comment: Looks like the link is now invalid. Only takes you to a search screen with list of topics.

Comment: Well, that was over 6 years ago... : ) Anyway, I replaced it with an equivalent working link. Please vote up if it's useful! See also https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539413/pdf-fonts

Answer (score 0):

You could try out a few things, have you look into the reportFont element?

```
<!ELEMENT reportFont EMPTY> 
<!ATTLIST reportFont
     name CDATA #REQUIRED 
     isDefault (true | false) "false" 
     fontName CDATA #IMPLIED 
     size NMTOKEN #IMPLIED 
     isBold (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     isItalic (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     isUnderline (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     isStrikeThrough (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     pdfFontName CDATA #IMPLIED 
     pdfEncoding CDATA #IMPLIED 
     isPdfEmbedded (true | false) #IMPLIED
>
```

However, note that report fonts are now deprecated, so you might wanna check out the style element:

```
<!ELEMENT style (conditionalStyle*)> 
<!ATTLIST style
     name CDATA #IMPLIED 
     isDefault (true | false) "false" 
     ...
     forecolor CDATA #IMPLIED 
     isStyledText (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     fontName CDATA #IMPLIED 
     fontSize NMTOKEN #IMPLIED 
     isBold (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     isItalic (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     isUnderline (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     isStrikeThrough (true | false) #IMPLIED 
     pdfFontName CDATA #IMPLIED 
     pdfEncoding CDATA #IMPLIED 
     isPdfEmbedded (true | false) #IMPLIED
     pattern CDATA #IMPLIED 
     isBlankWhenNull (true | false) #IMPLIED
>
```

pdfFontName should be the name of the font you are planning to use. This could either be a predefined PDF font or the name of a TTF file *present in the classpath*. In case you are using a TTF then note that isPdfEmbedded specifies whether an external TrueType font (TTF) file should be included in the PDF file or not

Regards!